# Why does PHP exec() command launch a DOS window? Can I hide this?

Tags: php, apache, cgi

I am executing a PHP script as a cgi-script on Windows XP, web server is Apache 2.2 which is encrypted using `phtmlenc()`. This is opening a blank DOS prompt (cmd.exe window) during execution.

This the test script test.php I have placed my script inside cgi-bin directory:

```
#! C:/PHP/bin
exec(WHOAMI);
```

When I launch the script through Internet Explorer by typing `localhost/cgi-bin/test.php`
I can see a DOS window popup.

1. Can I suppress this by changing Apache configuration or PHP
   configuration?
2. The original script is encrypted using a `phtmldec()` and hence I cannot change the actual `exec()` call
3. Can I edit the PHP to put some headers to hide or suppress the DOS window?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the window because that is under the control of the operating system, not PHP or Apache. And since `whoami` is a console application it creates a console when run.

By the way, `'WHOAMI'` should be in quotes.

Comment: Thanks jon , but i have an observation , i see the console window only when i run this php as a cgi-script , When i load the php installation as an apache module and execute as normal php (without the header i have given in my code ) the windows is not seen.

Comment: Just to give a bigger picture i have to keep this php 4.3.9 installation separate because the phtmldec.dll ( decrytption) is compatible with only with php.4.3.9

Comment: Before migration i had php 4.3.9 and apache  compiled with VC 6 also there was no dos window, but now i had to migrate php 5 and apache 2.2 compiled with vc 10, and i see that my dll is not working so i had to keep the php4.3.9 also and run php scripts under this as cgi